# How to add routes for gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a new gem that I want to use for some Rails apps. What I need is this:

I want to create some routes for different resources that goes to the same gem controller. Also I need to be able to let the user tell the gem that instead of using the gem's default controller it should use a controller in the current app (inheriting from the controller in the gem). I think this is something similar to what Devise does, but I don't fully understand how does it work.

Also I have already tried to use a custom Engine, but that creates some global routes and I can't make it to create the routes specific for some resources.

The ideal use case would be something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Some routes
  resources :users do
    Gem::Routes.define # Or something similar
  end

  resources :admins do
    Gem::Routes.define to: AdminController # Or something similar
  end
end
```

And my hopes are that the routes get created like:

```
POST   users/:id/something    gem_controller#something
POST   users/:id/something2   gem_controller#something2
POST   users/:id/something3   gem_controller#something3

POST   admins/:id/something    admins_controller#something
POST   admins/:id/something2   admins_controller#something2
POST   admins/:id/something3   admins_controller#something3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not look at what Devise does if you suspect it'll answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  concern :whatever do
    member do
      post :something
      post :something2
      post :something3
    end
  end

  resources :users, controller: 'gem' do
    concerns :whatever
  end
  resources :admins, controller: 'admin' do
    concerns :whatever
  end
end
```